# Create metric-compatible font

Tags: fonts, font-size

How can I create a font that is metric-compatible with a commercial font?
I don't need actual glyphs, just rectangles that will preserve the document layout.

What properties are important?
Advance width, left side bearing, line spacing, kerning, something else?

Caladea and Carlito are metric-compatible with Cambria and Calibri.
How they were created with the same metrics without violating the font license?